# How to append to existing apache arrow array

Tags: rust, apache-arrow

I can create an arrow array with a `builder`:

```rust
extern crate arrow;
use arrow::array::Int16Array;

// Create a new builder with a capacity of 100
let mut builder = Int16Array::builder(100);

// Append a slice of primitive values
builder.append_slice(&[2, 3, 4]).unwrap();

// Build the array
let finished_array = builder.finish();
```

But once I have finished building the array (thus called `.finish`), is there any option to create a new `builder` with the data of`finished_array` without copying the data into a new `builder`?

What I basically want is a cheap `append` operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some more, I found out arrow arrays are alway immutable. An append operation to an array is not possible. If you want a zero copy append like behavior, you can write/ use a `chunked array` (this is not yet available in `rust`, but for instance is supported in `pyarrow`